# Is this polar equation correct?

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Find the area of the region bounded by: 
$$r=5\cos(10\theta),~~~~~ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

When I did this, I got $\frac{1}{2\sin(20\pi)}-\frac{1}{2\sin(0)}$ getting $0$, is this correct?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You need to use the proper recipe for calculating area in polar coordinates.

Comment: How did you evalate the area? If you add your work it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Ok, I squared the r and then followed though.
I got 25pi. Didn't half it yet

Comment: That is the correct approach and the area is indeed $25\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{-\pi/20} ^ {\pi/20} \dfrac12 r^2 d \theta$$

is area of each of 20 rose petals.